# What was the status of Ibliss before being rejected?

Tags: shaitan

As we know, Ibliss was rejected (Rajeem) by Allah after refusing to prostrate. I wanted to know the status of Ibliss before this event. I have heard many things but do not have the  evidence. For example, I have heard the following about Ibliss:

- he was a leader and imam of angels;
- he was a guardian of heaven;
- he was given authority over the lower heavens and the earth.

So many question, what the status of Ibliss before being `rajeem`?

Comment: I don't know where you heard these three statements, but I don't know of any of them been quoted by an acceptable source. The qur'an actually confirms that Iblees was created from fire so he can't be an angel!

Comment: I didn't say he is an angel, I wrote leader of angels. I have asked this question because I have heard these statements, tried looking for evidence and didn't find. I have put this here only so that I can confirm whether there is such evidence or others agree that nothing such is true. I'm not a proponent of these statements

Comment: There are many tales about "The Fallen One" in so many religions and cultures.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, he was not Angel. It is mentioned in the Quran that he was and still is a Jinn.

Surah Al Kahf chapter 18 verse 50 the Qur’an says:

> "Behold! We said to the angels, "Bow down to Adam." they bowed down
> except Iblis He was one of the Jinns." [Al-Qur’an 18:50]

According to the sources, Iblis was living with angles but he was not one of them(angels) and there is no authentic source that mentions Iblis holding any of the positions that you have mentioned in your question. He was just a creature of Allah. Before disobeying Allah he was worshiping Allah but when Iblis didn't bow down to Hazrat Adam A.S then he was rejected or became *Rajeem*.

Comment: Look at my comment in the question above, the one on Jan 28, i made it clear that i'm not saying he is an angel, i don't understand why answers are pointing to this fact when this was never my point

Comment: Yes, I know. I cleared your point in the second paragraph of my answer that he was not holding of the positions from three of those that you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Imam Sadiq was asked: Is Iblis one of the angels or is he one of the other heavenly beings? He said: "It is neither from angels nor from other heavenly beings; Rather, he is a jinn, but he was with the angels, and the angels also thought that he was of their kind, but God knew that he was not the angel. This process continued until during the prostration of Adam, the hidden secret of Iblis was revealed.[ref](https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa857)